# Upload image using Multer on Next.js

Tags: mongoose, next.js, base64, multer, next.js14

In my Next.js 14 project, I have installed [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/). I created a schema with a `name` and an `image` field to add books to the database.

Now I can't upload pictures with Multer. After uploading the image, I want to save it in base64 in the database.
How can I do it?

My schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// schema design
const bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    image: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    },

}, {
    timestamps: true,
})

bookSchema.methods.logger = function () {
    console.log(` Data saved for ${this.name}`);
}

const BookSchema = mongoose.model('books', bookSchema)

module.exports = BookSchema;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Make the type of the `name` field `String` instead of `string` (capitalize first letter). JavaScript is case-sensitive, so that matters. As shown in the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Comment: The last line should have `module.exports`, not `module. Exports` (big E and a whitespace in the middle)

Comment: And finally always store files in the MongoDB database by using the mongoose data type `Buffer` and **not** String (which would be very inefficient here). As shown in this guide [Upload and Retrieve Image on MongoDB using Mongoose ~ GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upload-and-retrieve-image-on-mongodb-using-mongoose/), just search (Str + F) for `mongoose.Schema` on this page and you'll see what I mean.